# What keeps BackgroundWorker alive?

Tags: c#, backgroundworker

I use a BackgroundWorker as seen typically:

```
void ProcessWithBackgroundWorker()
{
    var worker = new BackgroundWorker();

    worker.DoWork += delegate (object o1, DoWorkEventArgs e1)
    {
        // my code
    };

    worker.RunWorkerCompleted += delegate (object o2, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e2)
    {
        // my code
    };

    worker.RunWorkerAsync();
}
```

This has not caused issues; the work is performed in the background and can take a long time to run.  But what keeps the `worker` instance alive after `ProcessWithBackgroundWorker` exits scope?

Comment: Garbage collector reference counting?

Comment: Yeah but who increments the reference?  When the function goes out of scope, nothing is referencing `worker`.

Comment: How do you know it stayed alive? GC does not work immediately.

Comment: @Yacoub, I don't, that is why I am asking to see if their is a potential bug here.  But I have seen numerous code samples that do exactly this.

Comment: It is the unnamed *this* variable.  Not visible in your code, it is a local variable buried in the framework code (BackgroundWorker.WorkerThreadStart) and is on the stack when your DoWork event handler runs, passed through *sender*.  Last time it is used is just before your RunWorkerCompleted event handler runs, if any.

Comment: Thanks @Hans -- good to know the framework supports this, although it seems the GC could destroy `worker` while my `RunWorkerCompleted` is still running.  I wish this were better documented.  It seems `BackgroundWorker` was originally derived from `Component` and supposed to be used in a `Windows.Form` so the `Form` would own it.

Comment: @DavidChing, but remember there are still things going. When your method ends, there is still an active thread running with a callstack and events wired up to the object. Even if the GC handles removing "worker", everything it sees says it should not dispose of it. I am not sure on the events in terms of local variables, but I do know events are the one gotcha in terms of possible memory leaks because the GC sees a reference count.

Comment: "The form owns it" is the wrong mental model.  It at best adds one more reference.  But never good enough to stop the BGW object from getting collected.  In particular it just keeps running when the form is closed and disposed, a pretty common bug.  It is the worker thread that "owns" it.  As anybody would (should) expect.

Comment: @TyCobb - I'm not aware that the events keep the object alive, but I will investigate and report back.  @Hans - thanks for making it obvious the thread owns the `BackgroundWorker` but to a user, the owner is who declares it, not some hidden thread.